# c++ return an instance of the same class

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I have something like this:

```
class BinaryTree
{
    ...
    virtual BinaryTree* GetLeft()
    {
        return this->root->left;
    }
    ...
}

class BinarySearchTree : public BinaryTree
{
    ...
}
```

My problem is that when I call `mySearchTree->GetLeft()` I get an object of the type `BinaryTree` and not `BinarySearchTree`.

Is there a way to defining a method that its return type = its containing class? Or should I redefine GetLeft in any subclass?

Comment: Just because you're returning a pointer to a `BinaryTree` doesn't necesarrily mean that the thing it actually points to isn't something derived from `BinaryTree` -- like a `BinarySearchTree` for example.  Not enough code posted to know more.

Comment: Look up [covariant return type](http://www.lwithers.me.uk/articles/covariant.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `GetLeft()` is defined on `BinaryTree` it will always return a `BinaryTree`. However, you could safely downcast to a `BinarySearchTree` in your case. You should test that this is safe to do before doing so.

Another thought: why do you need to do this? Perhaps it indicates that your `BinaryTree` API is not quite what you want.